# Scandic ä ö google chrome and chromium with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, google-chrome, chromium

Issues with google chrome and chromium, these browser(s) does not support scandic ä and ö with htaccess authorization?
htaccess authorization without ä and ö works fine.
Same htaccess (with ä and ö) works fine with firefox, safari and IE. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: You mean the `AuthBasic` authentication flow with username + password credentials?

Comment: yes, I'm not aware if this appears anywhere else, but I have had and have problems with htaccess authentication

Comment: Anyone found yet fix to this ?

Comment: Any workaround / fixes ?

Comment: I started wondering whether the server has some UTF-8 settings that should be enabled manually. Did you check if Apache config has something related to unicode?

Comment: Yes, apache works just fine and login works with every other browser except chrome. Also we have php curl incoming which works just fine with those login details.

Comment: I guess this should be raised as a bug to the Chromium project. Did you check if someone else has reported this issue at their bug tracker?